# External macro definition in header

Tags: compilation, macros, include, header-files, preprocessor

I have a main and a header in C.

i want to define some stuff, like:

```
main.c:
#include <header.h>
#define a
```

and use "a" as a macro even in header.h.

The header will be compiled statically with the main.
I'm doing this to be more clear in definition of important stuff and even because I need "a" even in the main.

How can I achieve this?
Can I put some sort of

```
#define extern a
```

in the header?

Edit: I'm thinking of merging the files, so that there is no actual issue